# Editor Template not binding in MVC3 class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have a PersonName class that look like this:

```
 public class PersonName
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a UserCreateModel that is composed of PersonName among other properties like this:

```
  public class UserCreateModel
    {

        public PersonName FullName { get; set; }               
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        ...........
    }
```

I have a Editor template in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PersonName.cshtml that looks like this (trimmed down):

```
@model PersonName

First: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName) 
Last: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName) 
Middle: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Middle)
```

However when I do (short version) :

```
@model UserCreateModel
 @{Html.BeginForm("Create", "User");}
        @Html.EditorForModel()  
 @{Html.EndForm();}
```

The PersonName does not bind to the editor and does not show up at all. I even tried UIHint, but not sure what I am missing. Also how do I debug this issue?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an editor template for the `PersonName` class (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PersonName.cshtml`) but not for the `UserCreateModel` which is your main model. So you need to either write an editor template for the `UserCreateModel` class and use `EditorForModel` or specify the property `using EditorFor` like this:

```
@model UserCreateModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "User"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FullName)  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I will try that now. But shouldn't the default Object.cshtml render this model and recursively pickup the elements in the UserCreateModel base on UIHint or the datatype and render accordingly? I am asking because other string based properties in the class, like Email, are working fine. Does it have to do with the TemplateDepth in the default implementation? Sorry new to MVC so I might be missing the obvious.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. While I am not sure why it was not recursively picked up - The blog post by Brad Wilson seems to insinuate deep binding.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the exact code you use, i think you should change Model in lambda with m

```
    @model PersonName

First: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName) 
Last: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName) 
Middle: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Middle)
```

and not Model.Firstname, etc

Comment: Thanks @archil, yes it is m.FirstName. Corrected it in the original post. My bad. But this is not the issue.

Comment: -1. This should probably have been a comment; you're not providing any real answer to the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out this page. I think it is what you want. It is basically saying that you will have to create a custom template for the model. It is very thorough.

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

hope this helps you